# SMTP Timeout with vbSendMail VB6

Tags: email, vb6, smtp, connection-timeout

Strange problem with vbSendMail

Hi

I'm maintaining a legacy application in VB6. The client requires a new function which is to process a list of messages to send out emails. The application is an ActiveX exe which has no user interface. It is called every few minutes to process the queue from Task Scheduler. It is set to compile for unattended execution and therefore can not have any forms in it. It only has modules and class modules.

If I run vbSendMail from the Main module it seems to work OK. However, I am not able to declare the `vbSendMail.clsSendmail` component as `With Events`. If I try to do this VB objects with the message "Only valid in object module". So I simply declare it as follows :

`Private poSendMail As vbSendMail.clsSendMail`

This is all fine and the code works and as far as I can see sends out the emails (well they arrive when I use my own address!). However, I am not able to pick up the Status, Progress, SendSuccessful and most importantly the SendFailed events. So I have no way of knowing if the email was sent successfully or not.

I have tried to create a Class Module and from there I can instantiate `vbSendMail.clsSendmail` and can declare it with events as follows :

```
Private WithEvents oMail As vbSendMail.clsSendMail
```

This allows me to pick up the events from SendMail (and the code certainly seems to do that OK). However, the problem is that when declared in this way (and using code that reads exactly the same as in the Main module) I can't establish a connection to the mail server. I get a Status event followed some time later by a SendFailed event as follows:

```
Send Status: Connecting to SMTP Server (mySMTPServerName)...
Send Failed: Timeout occurred: The SMTP Host did not respond to the request
```

I don't understand why the code should behave any differently when configured through a class module as opposed to a standard module.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening or how I can resolve the issue in such a way that I can get positive confirmation from `vbSendMail.clsSendMail` that the email has actually been sent successfully ?

Many thanks for any help that anyone can offer.

Answer (score 0):

I was curious so I downloaded the current vbSendMail from [here](http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=109).

You get the source plus a word doc and sample code.

Here's the thing - the vbSendMail project from which I assume the dll is created, includes a form 'frmSck.frm' which acts as a container for the winsock control that is used as the SMTP communication component. There is a single sub on the form defined as:

```
Private Sub WinSck_Error(...)
```

My assumption (not tested) is that the unattended execution setting denies some aspect of form creation so that the winsock control is created, as per your experience, but that the winsock_Error() sub is not triggered - hence no error events being captured.

There is some light in the tunnel, in as far as in the source for the Class_Initialize() sub of clsSendMail there is mention that there is a formless alternative. However it also mentions that there are unresolved deployment issues so maybe the light is a train.

There may be some mileage in downloading from the link above and trying the formless approach.

Comment: Many thanks Vanquished Wombat. I also took a close look at the documentation and the source code thinking that in the last resort I might be able to code something different. The same thought about the hidden form using the winSck control also struck me might have some bearing on it being an unattended application. The but the weird thing was that vbSendMail appeared to work fine when declared and used in modMain (but of course you can't get the Event messages when declared in this way).

Comment: I eventually solved the problem and it seemed to have something to do with having more than one instance of vbSendMail in existence at any one time. I can declare vbSendMail With Events in a class module and pick up the progress and success/fail events. However, this ceases to work if I have an instance of vbSendMail declared and in existence in a standard module which I guess would have global scope.

Comment: Even stranger, if I instantiate first the class level module of vbSendMail and then subsequently instantiate the standard module vbSendMail then the events from the standard module instantiation get received by the class level instantiation (interesting !). By keeping strict control over the instantiation and destruction of vbSendMail instances and making sure that only one of them exists at any one time I appear to have resolved the problem.